# Checking the values in an array around a specific index

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a 2 dimensional array and what I want to do is search for a specific value around that index(so I want to check array[x-1,y], array[x,y-1] and so on).

My problem is when it will check index which is out of range. Is there someway to check them (I don't want to a lot of IF's checking if x-1 or y-1 is in range of course). I haven't used try/catch a lot yet, and I'm not sure how that works either, but can I ignore the out of range Exception with that? Or is there a better solution for this problem?

Comment: You need to either check the length before accessing or you'll have to catch the exception.  You don't really have another option.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to use `if` to check for range?

Comment: The only reason is because then there would be lot of if's and I want to avoid it if possible.

Comment: I can currently only forsee one `if`, checking your upper bound for the array, (the lower bound is usually always 0).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't have `if` you can pre-compute lists of indexes for each cell and iterate over them. I.e. have separate array of the same dimensions that contains lists of index pairs for iteration. Inner elements would have 8 pairs each, corner and border elements would have less (3 and 5 correspondingly).

Alternatively you can use `? :` instead of `if` condition in case restriction is only on syntax and not on condition itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an *extension method* for hiding the logic in it (weather with `if`'s or with `Math.Max` and `Math.Min`):

```
  public static partial class Array2DExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> Vicinity<T>(this T[,] data, int line, int col) {
      if (null == data)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
      //TODO: you may want to add range check here

      for (int i = Math.Max(data.GetLowerBound(0), line - 1); 
               i <= Math.Min(data.GetUpperBound(0), line + 1); 
               ++i)
        for (int j = Math.Max(data.GetLowerBound(1), col - 1); 
                 j <= Math.Min(data.GetUpperBound(1), col + 1); 
                 ++j)
          yield return data[i, j];
    }
  }
```

And so you can put something like this:

```
  int[,] sample = ...
  ...
  // Are there any value less than 100 in vicinity of 5, 7 item?
  bool found = sample
    .Vicinity(5, 7)
    .Any(item => item < 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the safe lower and upper limits for both dimensions and then iterate over the matrix:

```
// Calculate x range to check
var xl = Math.Max(x-1, 0);
var xu = Math.Min(x+1, array.GetUpperBound(1));

// Calculate y range to check
var yl = Math.Max(y-1, 0);
var yu = Math.Min(y+1, array.GetUpperBound(0));

// Iterate using ranges
for (var j=yl; j <= yu; j++)
    for (var i=xl; i <= xu; i++)
    // Do the checking
    // array[j, i]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll have to check for each index if it around the array edges.
with the necessary "if's"

if you want to use try and catch it will work,
but you'll have to surround each array access with it's own Try And Catch
(if all will be in same try, once exception was caught the following commands will be skipped)

like this:

```
try
{
    array[x-1,y] 
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)            
{                

}

try
{
    array[x,y-1] 
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)            
{                

}

etc..
```